# IIS Process ID for pool

Tags: iis

How do you find out which process in the task manager belongs to what IIS app pool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SysInternal's Process Explorer - It will show the command line for the proces, which shows the AppPool Name.

Answer (score 4):

Run CMD as Administrator, run C:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\appcmd.exe LIST WP

Answer (score 1):

```
c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe c:\windows\system32\iisapp.vbs
```

Comment: this appears to be an IIS 6 only script.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming IIS6, the best way is to use iisapp.vbs plus Task Manager.  iisapp.vbs maps the app pool id to the PID (which Task Manager doesn't do), but Task Manager gives you the real-time CPU and memory usage.  You can run iisapp simply by typing 'iisapp' from the command prompt.  In Task Manager make sure to add the PID column since it's not there by default on a new machine.

In IIS7 you would use "appcmd list wp" instead of iisapp.  For that you'll need to update your path or navigate to it.  The full command that will work is: "c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list wp"

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can go into the Component Services management console, expand My Computer, select the Running Processes node in the left pane and you should see a list of running processes for each web sites application pool and their PID numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Install the IIS "Debug Diagnostic Tool".

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en

Run it and look in the Processes tab. Look in the "Web application pool name" column.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @pradeep answer

Sometimes `C:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\appcmd.exe LIST WP`  yields an empty list (i.e. yields nothing, no result, blank, zero lines).  This will occur if there have been no requests since IIS last restarted.  Get on your web-browser, and query (request a web page from) the server; that will start a worker process, and your next attempt with `appcmd LIST WP` will show the new process.